# Not able to scroll using ListView in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, ios, listview, react-native

Learning ReactNative and trying to create a simple timeline using ListView, have tried different settings but not able to scroll with ListView. Have only tried for iOS not sure if it may be working for Android, Below is the complete code...

any help would be appreciated !

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ListView, Image, Text, TouchableHighlight, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

import data from './data.json';

const profileImage = require('./images/profile.jpg');
const backgroundImage = require('./images/background.jpg');
const heartImage = require('./images/plain-heart.png');

class MainApp extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
       var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
         rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
       });

  this.state = {
       dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data),
  };
}

renderRow(record) {
return(
  <View style = {styles.postContainer}>
    <View style = {styles.row}>
      <View style = {styles.iconContainer}>
        <Image source = {profileImage} style = {styles.icon} />
      </View>
      <View style = {styles.info}>
        <Text style = {styles.userName}>{record.name}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
    <Image source = {backgroundImage} style = {styles.backgroundImage}>
      <Text style = {styles.quote}>{record.text}</Text>
    </Image>
    <View style = {styles.row}>
      <View style = {styles.likeIconContainer}>
        <Image source = {heartImage} style = {styles.like} />
      </View>
      <View style = {styles.likeInfo}>
        <Text style = {styles.likeText}>{record.likes} likes</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  </View>
  );
 }

render() {
return (
  <View style = { styles.container }>
    <Text style = {  styles.pageTitle } > Timeline </Text >
    <ListView
        dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow = {this.renderRow}
    />
  </View >
 );
 }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container:{
 flex:1,
 backgroundColor:'#fff'
},
pageTitle:{
 backgroundColor: '#0f1b29',
 color: '#fff',
 fontSize: 18,
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 padding: 10,
 paddingTop: 40,
 textAlign: 'center',
},
postContainer:{
 backgroundColor:'#fff'
},
row:{
 borderColor: '#f1f1f1',
 borderBottomWidth: 1,
 flexDirection: 'row',
 marginLeft: 10,
 marginRight: 10,
 paddingTop: 20,
 paddingBottom: 20,
},
iconContainer:{
 alignItems: 'center',
 backgroundColor: '#feb401',
 borderColor: '#feaf12',
 borderRadius: 25,
 borderWidth: 1,
 justifyContent: 'center',
 height: 50,
 width: 50,
},
icon:{
 height: 22,
 width: 22,
},
info:{
 flex: 1,
 paddingLeft: 25,
 paddingRight: 25,
},
userName:{
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 fontSize: 16,
 marginBottom: 5,
},
backgroundImage:{
 height: 250,
 width:width
},
quote:{
 position: 'absolute',
 fontSize:24,
 fontWeight:'bold',
 color: '#fff',
 backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
 borderRadius: 5,
 height: 250,
 padding: 25,
 top: 30,
 right: 10,
 left: 10
},
likeIconContainer:{
 alignItems: 'center',
 backgroundColor: '#feb401',
 borderColor: '#feaf12',
 borderRadius: 25,
 borderWidth: 1,
 justifyContent: 'center',
 height: 50,
 width: 50,
},
like:{
 height: 8,
 width: 8,
},
likeInfo:{
 flex: 1,
 paddingLeft: 25,
 paddingRight: 25,
},
likeText:{
 fontWeight: 'bold',
 fontSize: 8,
 marginBottom: 5,
}
});

export default MainApp;
```

Below is json file with data;

```
[
 {
  "name":"Vipin Dubey",
  "text": "While meditating we are simply seeing what the mind has been doing all along.",
  "likes": 5
 },
 {
  "name":"Vipin Dubey",
  "text": "Suffering is due to our disconnection with the inner soul. Meditation is establishing that connection .",
  "likes": 100
 },
 {
  "name":"Vipin Dubey",
  "text": "Self-observation is the first step of inner unfolding.",
  "likes": 85
 },
 {
  "name":"Vipin Dubey",
  "text": "When meditation is mastered, the mind is unwavering like the flame of a candle in a windless place.",
  "likes": 146
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem in your listview height so try setting listview height as per your requirement or set `flex:1` on listview style property and remove flex in outer view.

Cheers :)

Comment: removing flex from outer view hides everything, and adding flex 1 or height to list also does not work somehow.

Comment: give device height to outer view

Comment: and give listview height as 100 then check it scrolls or not

Comment: after that set listview height according to you

Comment: It's working on my side, you might be getting error of width?

Comment: backgroundImage:{
 height: 250,
 width:width
},

Comment: width variable is not defined, just give value to it :)

Comment: Extremely sorry for this stupid question, I was trying to scroll using two fingers in my Macbook and it does not work, however it works if I try to drag up or down. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136580/discussion-between-codesingh-and-vipin-dubey).

Comment: No problem brother :)

Answer (score 0):

Extremely sorry for this stupid question, I was trying to scroll using two fingers in my Macbook and it does not work, however it works if I try to drag up or down. Thanks for all the help.